# Can't copy a file using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL coding and hope someone can help me. I have a problem with an old program that I can't figure out. The program allows users to upload file which it saves in a separate directory and it saves the name and path to the files in a SQL database. I have to retrieve the path and file name from the database and then copy the file to another directory where the user can retrieve the file.  I don't have admin privileges on the database or server. The code works fine until it get to the Write method and then it breaks and I get the message Error -2146825287 creating object.

This is what the file path looks like that is stored in the database.

/TADS_FileArchive/820045_1_10192000_143042_82-0045-1.doc

I have tried changing slashes to back slashes but it didn't work. I have even put the exact path to a file in the @IMG_PATH with no luck, still get the error message on the Write method.  I read and  tried everything I know to figure the problem out without any luck. Thanks for any help.

```
USE TADS
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(MAX),
    @DOWNLOAD_PATH VARCHAR(MAX),
    @IMG_PATH varchar(MAX),
    @TIMESTAMP VARCHAR(MAX),
    @ObjectToken INT, 
    @START_TIME SMALLDATETIME,
    @END_TIME SMALLDATETIME,
    @hr int

SET @START_TIME = '01/01/2018'
SET @END_TIME = '12/31/2018'

SET @DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'D:\testfile\'

DECLARE IMGPATH CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT FILE_NAME, FILE_PATH from ATTACHED_FILES where DATE_ADDED between @START_TIME and @END_TIME

OPEN IMGPATH 

FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @NAME, @IMG_PATH  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @IMG_PATH = 'D:\TADS\TADS_SVN_WORKING_DIR\TADS_DEV2_WC'+@IMG_PATH
        SET @TIMESTAMP = @DOWNLOAD_PATH + @NAME

        PRINT @TIMESTAMP

        EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
        IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d creating object.', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END
    EXEC @hr =  sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
    IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d creating object.', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END
    EXEC @hr =  sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
    IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d creating object.', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END
    EXEC @hr =  sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @IMG_PATH
    IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d creating object.', 16, 1, @hr)
    RETURN
END
    EXEC @hr =  sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @TIMESTAMP, 2
    IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d creating object.', 16, 1, @hr)
   RETURN
END
    EXEC @hr =  sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
    IF @hr <> 0  
BEGIN  
    RAISERROR('Error %d creating object.', 16, 1, @hr)
   RETURN
END
    EXEC @hr =  sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken

    FETCH NEXT FROM IMGPATH INTO @NAME, @IMG_PATH  
END 

CLOSE IMGPATH
DEALLOCATE IMGPATH
```

Comment: Are there any other errors or warnings beside `Error -2146825287 creating object`?

Comment: I think the key is that you don't have admin privilege. This is likely to run under the service account  - writes usually need admin level access to the filesystem.

Comment: Can't you fix the application to store the uploaded file where you want it instead of saving it to disk and then copying it with t-sql? This is really not the right tool for this job.

Comment: No that is the only error that I get.  If i don't put the error checking in, it works except the files it creates don't have any data in them.  Sorry I do have admin on my test machine but not on the server.  No I can't change the code, don't have access to it, just the database to run queries on it